# Problem with WP_query

Tags: wp-query

I have a very annoying issue with 2 wp_query.

1. Showing 1 post - feature post

   ```
    <?php 
    $do_not_duplicate = array(); 



    $args = array (
   'post_type'  => 'post',
   'posts_per_page'  => '1',

   );

   $my_query = new WP_Query( $args );
   if ($my_query->have_posts()) :
   while($my_query->have_posts()) :
   $my_query->the_post();
   $do_not_duplicate[] = $post->ID; 
   get_template_part( 'content-feat',get_post_format() );
    endwhile;
   endif;
   wp_reset_postdata(); 

   ?>
   ```
2. The rest of the posts

   ```
   <?php 


           // the query to set the posts per page to 6
       query_posts($args);
       $args = array(
           'posts_per_page' => 6, 
           'paged' => $paged,

           );


       $my_query = new WP_Query( $args );
       if ($my_query->have_posts()) :
       while($my_query->have_posts()) :
       $my_query->the_post();
           if ( !in_array( $post->ID, $do_not_duplicate ) ) { // check IDs         

               get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() );
           }

           endwhile;
           endif;

        ?>
   ```

**The problem:**

Second loop is removing the post from first query (like its suppose to do) and should show 6 posts.

The problem is that is showing on first page 5 posts and on second 6 posts. I don't know where is the problem, can u guys help me? I'm kinda stuck with this issue. Thx

Comment: what you describe is exactly what I'd expect it to do. what do you expect to happen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your second block of code is strange.  The use of `query_posts()` doesn't really make sense. I don't even know what that is intended to do. Additionally, that is not really the best way to exclude posts from a Loop, and is what is causing your 5 vs. 6 posts issue.

You need to exclude the "do not duplicate" post with query arguments.

```
$args = array(
  'posts_per_page' => 6, 
  'paged' => $paged,
  'post__not_in' => $do_not_duplicate,
);

$my_query = new WP_Query( $args );
if ($my_query->have_posts()) {
  while($my_query->have_posts()) {
    $my_query->the_post();
    get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() );
  }
}
```

What is happening that is causing confusion is that your query returns 6 results but that includes the post you want to exclude. When you exclude that in your Loop, you end up with only 5 posts.